# Cannot delete channel image

Tags: devdemon, channel-images

I have a channel image field set in one of my channels. Curiously this field allows me to delete an image from one channel entry but on another channel entry it allows me to unlink the image instead.

I can't find out why.
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete images if that was the place it was originally uploaded. Once an image is uploaded it can be "linked" from other entries. Since that is not the original entry where the image exists you can only "unlink" it and you must delete from the original.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed that in the end but it is great to know that I was correct.  I guess that means that if you delete an image that is linked to elsewhere then the image is lost in the other location?  I hope that that scenario comes with a warning?